# Laravel 4 Migration Error

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I'm getting the following error when trying to create migrations for my laravel 4 installation. The file gets created but it outputs the following error.

```
Created Migration: 2014_07_06_073213_create-users-table
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
{"error":
{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'ClassPreloader\\Command\\PreCompileCommand' not found","file":"\/home\/name123\/domain.com\/laravel\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/OptimizeCommand.php","line":113}}[warehouse]

$ php artisan migrate:make create-users-table
```

It doesn't seem that there are any other people having the same problem.

Also getting this error when i commit the migration

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function increments() on a non-object","file":"\/home\/dandel26\/danieldelcore.com\/laravel\/app\/database\/migrations\/2014_06_29_092641_create_users_table.php","line":15}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes you can get autoload-baser errors from using a too-old version of composer (one that doesn't support PSR-4 when one of your dependencies relies on it). Try doing a `composer selfupdate` in the terminal and see if that helps the `migrate:make` command's error. Failing that, try removing the `vendor` directory entirely and running `composer install` to get a fresh install of all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks mate, that seems like the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In you're migration you have the function up. In this function there will be something like:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

It would seem that you did not do define the callback with the variable $table. Please add `Blueprint $table` and it should work.

In that case remember to import the right namespaces:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```